# WPF TextBox Binding Desync

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an issue where binding a textbox seems to desync from the underlying property. The **first** time the underlying property is updated, the textbox does not update. Then, if the underlying property is updated again, the textbox is updated with the original update. This sliding window behavior seems to continue over time. Am I doing something stupid?

I'm using .NET 4.7, vs 2017 community

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxBugTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxBugTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="225">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Width="55" Height="23" Text="{Binding Test}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="test2" Grid.Column="1" Width="55" Height="23"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="23" Width="50"
            Click="Button_Click" Content="update"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainWindowVM _vm;
    private int counter = 1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new MainWindowVM();
        DataContext = _vm;
        test2.Text = "test";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = counter++;
        _vm.Test = $"test{current}";
        test2.Text = $"test{current}";
    }
}
```

### MainWindowVM.cs

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _test) on_prop_changed();
            _test = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        Test = "test";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void on_prop_changed([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am such an idiot.

```
private string _test;
public string Test
{
    get { return _test; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _test) on_prop_changed();
        _test = value;
    }
}
```

should be

```
private string _test;
public string Test
{
    get { return _test; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _test)
        {
            _test = value;
            on_prop_changed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing an answer, you could as well have deleted your question. Since you just made a simple typographical error, the answer will unlikely be helpful for future readers.